# onSubmit in react for multiple items

Tags: reactjs

I have a series of data in which there is a form in every item and by submitting it a 'submitted' text must be shown, but the issue is that on submitting the form of one item, the 'submitted' text in all items is shown. I want that when I submit the form, the text of the div which is in the respected item should show.I try to use 'index' in onSubmit event and when i check index of 'for loop' in console it show me the correct index, but when i check index of handleSubmitR=(e, DetailsRoom, index)=>{console.log(index)} it is different form the index in 'for loop' and all submitted text will be shown.

```
     class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          resultEdit:{},
                    };
                $.ajax({
                url:"/json.bc",
                type:"post",
                data:{
                    cityid:"[##cms.form.cityid##]",
                    fdate:"[##cms.form.fdate##]", 
                    tdate:"[##cms.form.tdate##]", 
                    userid:"[##db.userid.userid##]",
                },
                success:(result)=>{
                this.setState({data: eval(result)});
                }
                })

      }
      renderHotel(){
        return this.state.data.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).map((item,i)=>{
          return (
            <div class="items">
            {this.renderDetailsRoom(item,i)}
           </div>
          )
        })
      }

    renderDetailsRoom(DetailsRoom,i){
    let lenfamilies = DetailsRoom.families.length 
    var indents =[];
    for(var j = 0 ;j <lenfamilies;j++){
        var  index= i+j
        indents.push(<form method="post" key={index}  action={this.renderAction(DetailsRoom)}  onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmitR(e, DetailsRoom, index)}><div  class="Result">{this.state.resultEdit[index]}</div></form>)
    }
    return(
      indents
      )
    }

    handleSubmitR=(e, DetailsRoom, index)=>{
    console.log(index)
    e.preventDefault();
    return  this.setState( prevState => ({
    resultEdit: { ...prevState.resultEdit, [index]:'submitted'},
    })) }
   render() {
        return (
         <div>{this.renderHotel()}</div>);
      }

    }
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Result'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your index is not unique.

```
for(var j = 0 ; j<lenfamilies; j++) {
  var index= i+j
  ...
  }
```

**i** is from map e.g. 0,1,2 **j** is from for loop e.g. 0,1,2, then **index** is 0,**1**,*2*,**1**,*2*,***3***,*2*,***3***,4

Comment: Thanks Boris Traljić.I try to make the index to be unique by this form:

Comment: var numF = i;
            var numS = j;
            var stingF = numF.toString();
            var stingS = numS.toString();
            var  index= stingF+stingS

Comment: but when the index of one of my form in for loop is '10' , the amount of index in onSubmit event id '111' ???How could it be happen??

Comment: I found the problem. When i have to forms by indexs : '00' and '01' in for loop , the indexs of both of them in onsubmit event are '01'. How it can be solved??Any idea?

Comment: I suggest index=i*lenfamilies+j;

Comment: It can be correct, but there is no different in the result of index in onsubmit event. The onsubmit event doesn't return correct number of index.